# How to manage vertical dropdown menu on mouseover?

Tags: jquery, html, css, drop-down-menu, jquery-hover

I have and vertical [dropdown menu](http://jsfiddle.net/gEMJs/) which is working fine, but when i mouseover the tab `Stateroom Details` just after `Account Details` tab then it move up, is there any alternate for this problem?.

I am adding fiddle for [this](http://jsfiddle.net/gEMJs/)

Comment: wats is ur requirement???
 mouse over on stateroom wat shd happen accordin to u??

Comment: if I directly hovering the stateroom tab then its working fine, but if I am trying to mouseover just after Account details then it moving up because of stateroom tab... I am looking for an alternate for this problem.

Comment: better use clickable menu instead of hover..
or instead of dropdown use normal menu bar
http://jqueryui.com/menu/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make them click to open would sort it? The menu above it to big so as it closes the others try to open if you mouse is still there. I would make them click to open menus, that would make more sense.